# postgresql configuration gives a blank page in Codeigniter (fail connection)

Tags: php, codeigniter, postgresql

I just created my PHP Application using CodeIgniter framework and PostgreSQL for the database, it run well on localhost. Then I moved the application into the server (xxx.xxx.1.77), but it gave a blank page when I try to run.

I removed all libraries and packages in autoload.php it run well. So I put it one by one and run it after I put each libraries/packages. Finally, I found the problem : Database.

This one will show welcome page (default), but when I call one of my controller that connect to a model, it will show a blank page.

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('session', 'form_validation');
```

This one will show a blank page at the first (welcome/default page won't show).

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('session', 'form_validation', 'database');
```

So, this is my database configuration:

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = '192.168.1.4';
$db['default']['port'] = '8432';
$db['default']['username'] = 'postgres';
$db['default']['password'] = '';
$db['default']['database'] = 'gstseminar';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'postgre';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

That configuration has no problem when I try to run my application on localhost.

Anyone knows about my problem? Any answer is appreciated.

Comment: might be related to your `pg_hba.conf` file. Postgres might not be open from outside by default.

Comment: Also some installations of postgresql default to listening only on localhost. Check the postgresql.conf for the setting `listen_addresses='*'`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how and why my project run well when I try to run it today. I looked at the config/database.php, and I found the configuration such as:

```
$active_group = 'default';
$active_record = TRUE;

$db['default']['hostname'] = '192.168.1.4';
$db['default']['port'] = '8432';
$db['default']['username'] = 'postgres';
$db['default']['password'] = '';
$db['default']['database'] = 'gstseminar';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'postgre';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = 'tb_';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

and on my config/autoload.php are:

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('session', 'form_validation', 'database');
```

It runs well now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

i think the port you use was wrong
try this :

```
$db['default']['port'] = '5432';
```

i think its the default port for postgre